# Enumeration of a complex type

Tags: xml, schema, xsd, enumeration

How can I make an enumeration of a complex type?

For example, I want to store the following data into a xsd enumeration called Measurings

- description
- tag
- item

item

tag fileName

each one of these attributes has an specific value and this set makes one registry in my ennumeration. But the problem is that as far as I know, it's allowed just the "value" attribute in an enumeration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing like complex type enumeration in XML Schema. You'll need to organize it externally. See

http://schemas.opengis.net/gml/3.1.1/base/dictionary.xsd
http://schemas.opengis.net/definitions/axisDirection.xml

for an implementation example.